# I have a string from a SQL Server table, that I want to be part bold on an ASP.NET Core page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core 6 C# application. I retrieve a string from a SQL Server database, to be displayed on a page, but I want part of that string to be bold. The string I have is:

```
"1st degree relative (18a) (parents, sibling, children)"
```

I want the "1st degree relative (18a)" part to be displayed as bold.

I tried saving the string as "1st degree relative (18a) (parents, sibling, children)" in the database with the b tags, but that didn't work

My page code is:

```
<div class="col-md-4"><label></label></div>
@foreach (var col in Model.HistoryColumns)
{
    <div class="col-md-2"><label>@col.Label</label></div>
}
</div>
```

My controller:

```
var theViewModel = new TheViewModel
    {
         HistoryColumns = _HistoryLabelsRepository.EnabledColumns().ToList(),
    };

return View("History", theViewModel);
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Don't save in the db, just use an html span to bold the text on the UI.

Comment: Yes, you can save the HTML string into the Database. And to display the HTML, use the `Html.Raw()`: `@Html.Raw(col.Label)`

Comment: @KevBarri that exposes you to script injection. Nothing prevents someone from storing a `<script>....</script>` block. It's *easier* to bold in HTML or even better, use the correct style

Comment: @KevBarri Be aware that this probably causes more security risks then you can think counter measures for. I would go for GHDevOps solution since it's much safer. This is even true when the data is not user generated. Your application might change in the future by a programmer not aware of your security flaw.

Comment: @KevBarri you're using Bootstrap already which means you can just add `class="text-danger"` or `fw-bold` or `badge rounded-pill bg-dark` to the label itself instead of injecting raw HTML. You can use predefined class strings and pick the one you want based on the data. There's no injection risk when you control the class names yourself

Comment: Another option is to [display your list horizontally](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/list-group/#horizontal) instead of using `div class="col"`. If you store the label and description parts separately you can probably use a `dl` list with `dt` and `dd` for the two parts

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store the HTML in the database. And to display/render the HTML, use [`Html.Raw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

```
@Html.Raw(col.Label)
```

Apart from that, you should be concerned about whether this HTML is inputted/controlled internally or by the external user. If your answer is external users, you should be aware of [HTML injection](https://medium.com/@prathameshghumade/understanding-and-preventing-html-injection-attacks-732ffafb0bfa) and implement preventive approaches such as validation, encoding, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Storing markup in the database is a bad idea, both for security reasons and because it prevents you from controlling how the data is displayed. Should someone store `<script>alert("You got hacked!!");<script>` in the database you'll get one alert box for every line.

You're already using Bootstrap which means there are a lot of ways to display a list of labels and text, as long as you store the title and content separately.

It seems you want to display a list of terms horizontally. Displaying a list of terms is normally done with `dl`. To show it horizontally, in Bootstrap 4 and later, apply `row` to the list and `col` to the elements:

```
<dl class="row">
@foreach (var col in Model.HistoryColumns)
{

    <dt class="col-2">@col.Title</dt>
    <dd class="col-2">@col.Content</dd>
}
</dl>
```

You could change this into a list of buttons and tooltips without modifying the data :

```
@foreach (var col in Model.HistoryColumns)
{

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
    data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" 
    title="@col.Content">
  @col.Title
</button>
}
```